# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/(test)/test1,test2

Tags: jquery, ezpublish, querystringparameter

I have a problem with jQuery (1.11.2). I have to build URL with parameters in  Query String like this : 
http://www.myhost.com/my/path/?search=ok#/(testA)/test1a,test2a/(testB)/testb1

But jQuery return to me "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/(testA)/testa1,testa2"

My code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = decodeURIComponent(document.location.href);
    console.log(url);
}
```

I don't see the problem, with old versions of jQuery, there wasn't any problems with this type of URL (i'm working with eZ Publish 5).

Thank you for yours answers :).

Answer (score 0):

H,

The cause of the error is the special characters within the attribute value

Comment: I need "#" in my URL because this parameters must be treated like anchor tags or else eZPublish (the CMS) 's going to interpret them in the"view parameters" :)